# React Native cannot resolve babel plugin

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, babeljs

**Error Message**

Unknown plugin \"require-all\" specified in "\project\directory\path\.babelrc.env.development"

**My files**

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source", "require-all"]

    }
   }
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "text-adventure-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-require-all": "0.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clear": "^0.1.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-typewriter": "^0.5.3"
  }
}
```

*babel-plugin-require-all*

installed via npm as described here:
https://github.com/dushaobindoudou/babel-plugin-require-all

**What I've tried**

- Changing "require-all" to "babel-plugin-require-all"
- Deleting and re-installing my node_modules
- Clearing npm cache
- Scoured the internet for advice on including babel plugins

Comment: I installed babel through this url : [https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-ii](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-ii) . They have explained really well, go through the process might be of some help for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link Zuha, informative regarding Babel settup, but unfortunately doesn't touch on plugins :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in the [`package.json`](https://github.com/dushaobindoudou/babel-plugin-require-all/blob/46cfd3370b0b9d38f5302c155da03b07ec04b569/package.json#L4%20%60package.json%60) for that plugin - there is an extra (space) in the `main` property which means babel can't resolve it. I verified this by removing the space from the end of the line, and it successfully compiles.

My advice in this case would be to use a different package (maybe something like https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-wildcard could help) or submit a pull request to the `babel-plugin-require-all` package to remove the extra space.

Comment: You're the man! I'll verify this Tuesday and get back to you. Until then I submitted a PR for the extra space

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this gets my past my current error however produces a new one. Now, I get "Cannot read property type of null" in Expo.js. This is called inadvertently from index.js in babel-plugin-require-all at line 62. This is done as babel-traverse attempts to create the node tree during compile time. Do you have any insights to that?

Comment: At this point, I'd seriously consider switching to another plugin. With babel@7 now being released, the babel-plugin-require-all will need to be updated to support the new flow. I'd recommend finding a plugin that already supports it.